# index out of string, ruby

Tags: ruby, string, indexing

Here's a small part of my code, pretty self explanatory, it copies all characters to temp from input and skips spaces.

```
input = gets.to_s.chomp
temp=String.new
for i in 0..input.length-1
  if (input[i]==" ")
    next
  else 
    temp[i]=input[i]
  end  
end
puts "#{temp},END"
gets
```

However, i tested it with a 'hello world' input, and it should've given me `helloworld` But i'm getting

```
8:in '[]=':index 6 out of string(IndexError)
```

meaning the problem starts while it's skipping the space, for some reason.
keep in mind that i don't get any errors if i put a string that doesn't contain a space

Comment: Why not just `puts gets.chomp.gsub(' ', '')`?

Comment: It's part of a bigger code i can't do that

Comment: You can definitely do something like it, if you're using the code in question. The way you've written this is *extremely* unidiomatic Ruby.

Comment: Instead of `String.new` just do `''`, it's the same thing and far less verbose. Ruby isn't like Java where you need to be overly specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your error is due to the difference between the string 'hello world' and that you're "rejecting" whitespaces. In such case, for each whitespace in the string being used, the temp will have one less.

You can assign the `input[i]` when isn't a whitespace to the temp variable in the position temp.size, this way you don't skip indexes.

It could be `temp[temp.size]` or just modifying temp with `+=`.

```
for i in 0...input.size
  if input[i] == ' '
    next
  else 
    temp[temp.size] = input[i]
  end  
end
```

Note you can replace the `for` loop for `each` (the Ruby way):

```
input = 'hello world'
temp  = ''
(0...input.size).each do |index|
  input[index] == ' ' ? next : temp[temp.size] = input[index]
end
# helloworld
```

Comment: temp.size, that's genius!

Answer (score 4):

Whenever string manipulation is required, it may be desirable to convert the string to an array of its parts, manipulate those parts and then join them back into a string, but [more often as not](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/more+often+than+not) it is simpler to just operate on the string itself, mainly using methods from the class [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html). Here you could [Kernel#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) the following.

```
"%s END" % gets.delete(" \n")
  #=> "helloworld"
```

[String#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-delete) removes both spaces and the return character (`"\n"`) that [Kernel#gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) tacks onto the end of the string that is entered. A variant of this is `"%s END" % gets.chomp.delete(" ")`.

Another way would be to `puts`

```
"%s END" % gets.gsub(/\s/, '')
  #=> "helloworld"
```

The regular expression `/\s/`, causes [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) to remove all whitespace, which includes both spaces (and tabs) that are entered and the `"\n"` that `gets` tacks on to the end of the string.

Comment: `delete`, `tr` and `gsub` are all good choices here. The currently accepted answer is a reworking of a fundamentally flawed approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip all white spaces from your input and print the output, you can do so with a one-liner:

```
puts "#{gets.chomp.split.join}, END"
```

In ruby, you hardly need to write loops using `for` construct unlike other traditional languages like Java.

Comment: I'm always mildly amused when I read (sic), "Here's a one-liner", followed by a single line of code. It's as though the reader might not recognize it as such without those words. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯